# Converting images to Pytorch tensors loses label data

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, tensor

I have a dataset of images. In the below code, I am trying to convert them to Pytorch tensors by first converting them to PIL images:

```
# choose the training and test datasets
train_data = os.listdir('data/training/')
testing_data = os.listdir('data/testing/')
train_tensors = []
test_tensors = []

# Print out some stats about the training and test data
print('Train data, number of images: ', len(train_data))
print('Test data, number of images: ', len(testing_data))

# The transformation call to resize images and transform them into Tensors
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop((120,120)),
    transforms.PILToTensor()
])

# Converting every train/test image to a PIL image and then to a Pytorch tensor
for train_image in train_data:
    img = Image.open('data/training/' + train_image)
    train_tensors.append(transform(img))

for test_image in testing_data:
    img = Image.open('data/testing/' + test_image)
    test_tensors.append(transform(img))
```

However, in this process, the labels are completely lost. This is the output of `train_tensors`

```
 [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255]],

        [[255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255]],

        [[255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 254, 254],
         ...,
         [254, 254, 255,  ..., 254, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255]],

        [[255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

When I use this tensor in a dataloader and try to extract the labels, I get a `too many values to unpack` error.

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_tensors, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

dataiter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = dataiter.__next__() #
```

How can I maintain my label data?

Comment: where is your label data to begin with? is it in the name of the image file?

Comment: @Shai Yes. I have the 3 classes saved in a list and images are named like `class_001.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had appended only transformed images to `train_tensors` with no labels.

Therefore, `dataiter.__next__()` will give you only the tensor you'd appended, but at the same time you're requiring 2 variables `images` and `labels`.

Append label information to the list or request for only one element will solve this error.